# Jquery Validation Engine with Conatct Form 7

Tags: validation

I am using contact form 7 and it's working with basic validations. But i have to do some advanced validation.

So i have to use https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine.

How can i use vaidation engine with Contact form 7?

Answer (score 0):

@Magecode, you won't be able to use that javascript library, however, you CAN use [Jquery Validation for Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-validation-for-contact-form-7/), instead. That should do exactly what you need. :)